# Task - bounded functional operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $r,x\in \mathbb{R}$ , $0<r<1$ and $A_{n,r}(f)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}r^{|k|}e^{ikx}f(r^k)$, for $f\in C(0,\infty)$,  $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$. Еxamine whether the $A_{n,r}$ bounded linear functional. If there is (uniformly) $\lim_{n \to \infty}A_{n,r}$ and $s-\lim_{n \to \infty}A_{n,r}$ for $r\in (0,1)$?

I can prove that $A_{n.r}$ are bounded linear functionals, but I can't do anything else.
(Sorry for my bad English.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionals converge in the norm,  because of the estimate 
$$ |r^{|k|}e^{ikx}f(r^k)| \le  r^{|k|} \|f\|_{C(0,\infty)}$$
where the right hand side is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: $|A_{n,r}(f)|=|\sum_{k=-n}^{n}r^{|k|}e^{ikx}f(r^k)|\leq \sum_{k=-n}^{n}r^{|k|}|e^{ikx}||f(r^k)|\leq \sum_{k=-n}^{n}r^{|k|}||f||_C  \leq ||f||_C \cdot(\frac{1+r}{1-r})$Can it be concluded from this uniform boundedness of $A_{n,r}$?

Comment: @Laki888 Yes, because the number $r$ is fixed: only $n$ changes. But uniform boundedness is not enough. You need $\|A_{n,r}-A_{m,r}\|$ to be small. This is where the convergent series helps: the norm of the difference is bounded by some tail of the convergent series.